# numpy masked array fill value still being accessed

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing

I am trying to process an image as a masked array to handle NoData areas. I decided to do a little testing first on one dimensional arrays, and am seeing something odd. here is my test code:

```
    a = np.array([0,1,4,3,4,-9999,33,34,-9999])
    am = np.ma.MaskedArray(a)
    am.mask = (am==-9999)

    z = np.arange(35)

    z[am]
```

I would expect that indexing the z array with the masked array would succeed but I am seeing the following error:

```
    Runtime error 
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    IndexError: index -9999 is out of bounds for size 35
```

can anyone comment on how this would be correctly coded? I can run the following command with success:

```
    z[a[a>0]]
```

which is effectively the same thing.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's generally a bad idea to use marked arrays for purposes of indexing, precisely because the behavior that should happen at a masked value is undefined.

Think about it this way: when I look at your array `a` and your array `z`, I can say "Ok, `a[0] = 0` so `z[a[0]]` makes sense." And so on until I come across `a[5] = -9999` when I can say, "OK, that can't make sense as an index for `z`" and an exception can be raised.

This is in fact what will happen when you naively use `am` as an index set ... it reverts to using `am.data` which contains *all* of the original values. If instead it tried to use something like `[z[i] for i in am]` you would run smack into the problem of encountering `numpy.ma.core.MaskedConstant` which is not a sensible value for indexing -- **not for fetching a value nor for ignoring the request to fetch a value**.

```
In [39]: l = [x for x in am]

In [40]: l
Out[40]: [0, 1, 4, 3, 4, masked, 33, 34, masked]

In [41]: type(l[-1])
Out[41]: numpy.ma.core.MaskedConstant
```

(In fact, if you try to index on one of these guys, you get `IndexError: arrays used as indices must be of integer (or boolean) type`).

But now what happens if I come across the masked value in `am.filled()`? The entry at the 5th index of `am.filled()` won't be an instance of `numpy.ma.core.MaskedConstant` -- it will be whatever fill value has been selected by you. If that fill value makes sense as an index, well then you will actually fetch a value by indexing at that index. Take 0 as an example. It seems like an innocuous, neutral fill value, but actually it represents a valid index, so you get two extra accesses to the 0th entry of `z`:

```
In [42]: am.fill_value = 0

In [43]: z[am.filled()]
Out[43]: array([ 0,  1,  4,  3,  4,  0, 33, 34,  0])
```

and this isn't exactly what the mask is supposed to do either!

A half-baked approach is to iterate over `am` and exclude anything with `type` of `np.ma.core.MaskedConstant`:

```
In [45]: z[np.array([x for x in am if type(x) is not np.ma.core.MaskedConstant])]
Out[45]: array([ 0,  1,  4,  3,  4, 33, 34])
```

But really a much clearer expression of all of this is to just use plain logical indexing in the first place:

```
In [47]: z[a[a != -9999]]
Out[47]: array([ 0,  1,  4,  3,  4, 33, 34])
```

Note that logical indexing like this will work fine for 2D arrays, as long as you're willing to accept that once a higher dimensional array is indexed logically, if the result is no longer conformable to the same regular 2D shape, then it will be presented in 1D, like this:

```
In [58]: a2 = np.array([[10, -9999, 13], [-9999, 1, 8], [1, 8, 1]])

In [59]: a2
Out[59]: 
array([[   10, -9999,    13],
       [-9999,     1,     8],
       [    1,     8,     1]])

In [60]: z2 = np.random.rand(3,3)

In [61]: z2[np.where(a2 != -9999)]
Out[61]: 
array([ 0.4739082 ,  0.13629442,  0.46547732,  0.87674102,  0.08753297,
        0.57109764,  0.39722408])
```

If instead you want something similar to the effect of a mask, you can just set values equal to `NaN` (for `float` arrays):

```
In [66]: a2 = np.array([[10, -9999, 13], [-9999, 1, 8], [1, 8, 1]], dtype=np.float)

In [67]: a2
Out[67]: 
array([[  1.00000000e+01,  -9.99900000e+03,   1.30000000e+01],
       [ -9.99900000e+03,   1.00000000e+00,   8.00000000e+00],
       [  1.00000000e+00,   8.00000000e+00,   1.00000000e+00]])

In [68]: a2[np.where(a2 == -9999)] = np.NaN

In [69]: a2
Out[69]: 
array([[ 10.,  nan,  13.],
       [ nan,   1.,   8.],
       [  1.,   8.,   1.]])
```

This form of masking with `NaN` is suitable for a lot of vectorized array computations in NumPy, although it can be a pain to worry about converting integer-based image data to floating point first, and converting back safely at the end.

Comment: Thanks Mr. F! That was a very thorough explanation, and I, as I'm sure others will, appreciate.

Comment: I wanted to add some more..I'm used to handling NoData areas fairly easily in image processing applications that require mathematic manipulation, transforms, etc., but I'm writing a histogram matching program which requires indexing and thus the attempted use of masked arrays. I think the looping approach is most appropriate for my specific use case. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
a = np.array([0,1,4,3,4,-9999,33,34,-9999])
am = np.ma.MaskedArray(a)
am.mask = (am==-9999)
np.ma.set_fill_value(am, 0)

z = np.arange(35)

print z[am.filled()]
```

accessing `am` gives the masked array where masked value refers to the original values(it is just a reference to the original array).Calling `am.filled()` after setting fill_value replaces the masked elements with the fill_value in the array returned by `am.filled`